# Will I always add withContext(Dispatchers.IO) in suspend when I pull data from a remote server?

Tags: kotlin, kotlin-coroutines

I'm learning Coroutines of Kotlin.

The following content is from the artical https://developer.android.com/kotlin/coroutines.

***Important: Using suspend doesn't tell Kotlin to run a function on a background thread. It's normal for suspend functions to operate on the main thread. It's also common to launch coroutines on the main thread. You should always use withContext() inside a suspend function when you need main-safety, such as when reading from or writing to disk, performing network operations, or running CPU-intensive operations.***

Normally it's spend long time when I pull data from a remote server, so I need to place "the pull data function" in background thread  in order not to freeze main UI.

Should I always add withContext(Dispatchers.IO) in suspend when I use suspend to pull data from remote server?

**BTW,**

The Code A is from the project https://github.com/googlecodelabs/kotlin-coroutines, you can see [it](https://github.com/googlecodelabs/kotlin-coroutines/blob/master/coroutines-codelab/finished_code/src/main/java/com/example/android/kotlincoroutines/main/MainViewModel.kt) .

But I can't find the keyword withContext() in the project, why?

**Code A**

```
fun refreshTitle() = launchDataLoad {
    repository.refreshTitle()
}


private fun launchDataLoad(block: suspend () -> Unit): Unit {
    viewModelScope.launch {
        try {
            _spinner.value = true
            block()
        } catch (error: TitleRefreshError) {
            _snackBar.value = error.message
        } finally {
            _spinner.value = false
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Don't use `withContext()` to call suspendable functions. They are main-safe.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

> Should I always add withContext(Dispatchers.IO) in suspend when I use suspend to pull data from remote server?

It depends. If the you use a library like `Retrofit 2.6.0` that has native support for `suspend`, the dispatcher is already `Dispatchers.IO` (or whatever the library deems more appropriate).

If the call to pull data from a remote server is blocking, you need to make sure to run it on `Dispatcher.IO` yourself with `withContext(Dispatchers.IO)` to not block the main thread.

> I can't find the keyword withContext() in the project, why?

Because the project uses Retrofit, so the switch to `Dispatchers.IO` happens under the hood:
https://github.com/googlecodelabs/kotlin-coroutines/blob/master/coroutines-codelab/finished_code/src/main/java/com/example/android/kotlincoroutines/main/MainNetwork.kt

Comment: Thanks! Does Room architecture also use Dispatchers.IO just like Retrofit ? Are there other popular library use Dispatchers.IO default?

Comment: Keep in mind that using `Dispatchers.IO` is not a good sign, it is a workaround for a legacy library that is stuck with using sync IO. It wastes resources and doesn't allow too many parallel fetches. A good Android library would simply be main-safe and work with any dispatcher.

Comment: @HelloCW The docs does not say exactly what Dispatcher is used.https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/room/accessing-data#kotlin-coroutines  Seems as if a Room-specific dispatcher is used. But that's nothing to worry about since the important thing is that the main thread is not blocked.

Comment: @MarkoTopolnik Yes, but there are tons of such legacy libraries around, for which `withContext` is a reasonable workaround.

Comment: My point is a different one: many users get the impression that you need `Dispatchers.IO` for _any_ IO and don't realize the workaround aspect of it at all.